# Change number in column

Tags: mysql

When using MySQL, how do you increase or decrease the number in a particular cell by a specified amount with a single query. For example I have a product table with 5 x product a. I sell 1 item and I want to update the field. I want to do it with one query, not get the number add to it and then update (I know how to do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update products set amount = amount + 1 where productId = 12345
```

If you are using prepared statements you can replace the amount to add as well as the product id with placeholders

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tbl SET col=col+1 WHERE id=1234
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Product SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE Id = xxx
```